# C# Delta Time Implementation

Tags: c#, time, timedelta

Heres a code snippet from my attempt to make a 2D particle sim

```
static long lastTime = 0;
static double GetDeltaTime()
{
    long now = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    double dT = (now - lastTime); // / 1000
    lastTime = now;
    Console.WriteLine(dT);
    return dT;
}
```

It should be pretty obvious that it would return the time (in milliseconds) since the last time that method was called. Only problem, this is what it prints

```
393
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

Ok so maybe thats just because each pass is taking less than a millisecond. So i changed it to

```
    static long lastTime = 0;
    static double GetDeltaTime()
    {
        long now = DateTime.Now.Ticks; // Changed this to ticks
        double dT = (now - lastTime); // / 1000
        lastTime = now;
        Console.WriteLine(dT);
        return dT;
    }
```

but that still prints

```
6.35476136625848E+17
20023
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

and if "particle simulator" isnt a good enough indicator of how complex my program is, let me just say, it takes a lot longer than 0 ticks to complete a pass!

So whats going on here?

------- Code Reference ------
Heres the whole class just for reference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace _2D_Particle_Sim
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static Particle2DSim pSim;
        static Form1 form;
        public static Thread update = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Update));

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]

        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            form = new Form1();

            pSim = new Particle2DSim(form);
            pSim.AddParticle(new Vector2(-80, -7), 5);
            pSim.AddParticle(new Vector2(8, 7), 3);

            Console.WriteLine("Opening Thread");

            Program.update.Start();

            Application.Run(form);

            // System.Threading.Timer timer;
            // timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Update), null, 0, 30);
        }

        static void Update()
        {
            GetDeltaTime();
            while (true)
            {
                pSim.Update(GetDeltaTime());
            }
        }

        static long lastTime = 0;
        static double GetDeltaTime()
        {
            long now = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            double dT = (now - lastTime); // / 1000
            lastTime = now;
            Console.WriteLine(dT);
            return dT;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if my analogy of how complex my code is still wasnt enough, heres the update methord from the Particle2DSim class

```
    public void Update(double deltaTime)
        {
              foreach (Particle2D particle in particles)
              {
                  List<Particle2D> collidedWith = new List<Particle2D>();

                  Vector2 acceleration = new Vector2();
                  double influenceSum = 0;

                  // Calculate acceleration due to Gravity
                  #region Gravity
                  foreach (Particle2D particle2 in particles)
                  {
                      double dist2 = particle.position.Distance2(particle.position);
                      double influence = dist2 != 0 ? particle2.mass / dist2 : 0;
                      acceleration.Add(particle.position.LookAt(particle2.position) * influence);
                      influenceSum += influence;

                      if (dist2 < ((particle.radius + particle2.radius) * (particle.radius + particle2.radius)) && dist2 != 0)
                      {
                          collidedWith.Add(particle2);
                      }
                  }
                  acceleration.Divide(influenceSum);
                  #endregion

                  particle.Update(deltaTime);

                  // Handle Collisions
                  #region Collisions
                  if (collidedWith.Count > 0)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Crash!");

                      double newMass = 0;
                      double newRadius = 0;

                      Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2();
                      Vector2 newVelocity = new Vector2();

                      newMass += particle.mass;
                      newRadius += Math.Sqrt(particle.radius);

                      newPosition += particle.position;

                      newVelocity += particle.velocity * particle.mass;

                      particles.Remove(particle);

                      foreach (Particle2D particle2 in collidedWith)
                      {
                          newMass += particle2.mass;
                          newRadius += Math.Sqrt(particle2.radius);

                          newPosition += particle2.position;

                          newVelocity += particle2.velocity * particle2.mass;

                          particles.Remove(particle2);
                      }

                      newPosition.Divide(collidedWith.Count + 1);
                      newVelocity.Divide(newMass);

                      AddParticle(newPosition, newVelocity, newMass, newRadius);
                  }
                  #endregion
              } 
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried not using `while(true)` and sleeping a bit? You'll end up wanting to do that anyways.

Comment: Be aware that `Millisecond` is from `0` to `999`. (Since you use `long`, you could expect it to be total milliseconds.)

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you're using `DateTime` to try to measure the passage of time. `DateTime` is meant for representing a date and time, but not for measuring elapsed time.

Use the `stopwatch` class for measuring time:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

// Do something here

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
// or sw.ElapsedTicks
```

For more details on the difference, check out Eric Lippert's blog [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/02/459952.aspx)

Comment: Stopwatch could be difficult to use in the context of a delta though. Otherwise not a bad suggestion, it could work.

Answer (score 5):

## DeltaTime like in Unity

```
using System;

class DeltaTimeExample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime time1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime time2 = DateTime.Now;

        // Here we find DeltaTime in while loop
        while (true)
        {
            // This is it, use it where you want, it is time between
            // two iterations of while loop
            time2 = DateTime.Now;
            float deltaTime = (time2.Ticks - time1.Ticks) / 10000000f; 
            Console.WriteLine(deltaTime);  // *float* output {0,2493331}
            Console.WriteLine(time2.Ticks - time1.Ticks); // *int* output {2493331}
            time1 = time2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this lock up unless you make it asynchronous? 

using System.Threading.Tasks;

           static async Task UpdateDeltaTime() { 
               while (true) { 
                   await Task.Delay(1);
               }
           }

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    
    static double DeltaTime;
    static double Secondframe;
    static double Counter;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
       
        while (true)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            double FirstFrame = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
            
            DeltaTime = FirstFrame - Secondframe;
            
           
            Counter += DeltaTime;
            Console.WriteLine(Counter);

            Secondframe = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Please give some explanation as to what your solution does

Answer (score 0):

**DeltaTime** class helps you implement the animation.

```
 public class DeltaTime
        {
            DateTime FirstTime;
            public static DeltaTimer CreatePoint()
            {
                return new DeltaTime(){ FirstTime = DateTime.Now};
            }
            public  TimeSpan GetDeltaTime()
            {
    
                if (FirstTime != null)
                {
                    
                    return DateTime.Now - FirstTime;
                }
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/60); //If null then return 60 FPS.
            }
        }
```

Example 1:

```
public async void TEST1_Animation(Button button)
        {
            var pointer=  DeltaTime.CreatePoint();
            for(double h = 0; h<button.Height;h++)
            {
                 var n= pointer.GetDeltaTime().TotalSeconds;
                h = h * n;
                await button.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { button.Height= h; });
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 60 * n));

            }
        }
```

And your code will look like this:

```
static void Update()
    {
        var Pointer = DeltaTimer.CreatePoint();
       
        while (true)
        {
            pSim.Update(Pointer.GetDeltaTime().TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```